# Локальная доменная зона

Tags: apache, hosts, linux

Добрый вечер, я занимаюсь разработкой веб-сайтов. Естественно разработка проходит на `localhost`. При создании нового виртуального хоста приходиться каждый раз прописывать его в `hosts`. Хотелось бы иметь локальную доменную зону, например `*.dev`

На борту Fedora 18, Apache 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если всё-таки хотите DNS, то:

- Установите себе bind
- Настройте локальную доменную зону
- Настройте форвардинг остальных запросов на (вашего провайдера|ваш роутер|8.8.8.8)

Этого в принципе должно хватить.

Мануалов по настройке много, вот один из них: [Установка и Настройка DNS-сервера BIND в RHEL, CentOS, Fedora](http://redhat-club.org/2011/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-dns-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-bind-%D0%B2-rhel-centos-fedora) а вот другой: `http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch18_:_Configuring_DNS`

Comment: буду копать, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

что то мне подсказывает, что вы не в том направлении копаете. Если хотите упростить процедуру добавления хоста, то просто создайте соответствующий баш скрипт.

Comment: подобную вещь я делал, но вопрос же не об этом